# AMD drivers NOT WORKING Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: drivers, 17.04

when booting it shows me the low-graphics mode but the "fix" ([How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error#218095)) didn't work for me.
it happened even with 16.10, did i miss something important in the installation? any workaround?

EDIT: currently own 2 R9 Furys in CF, in ubuntu system infos it detects them as "AMD® Fiji"

Comment: What drivers did you install and how?

Comment: When a device is bricked, it doesn't show anything, it doesn't show anything, doesn't boot, doesn't even make a noise. Apparently, it isn't the case, so, why the drama?

Comment: i installed the amdgpu-pro drivers

Comment: And your graphics cad is?... Please edit and add hardware specs.

Answer (score 0):

When you get to the blank screen, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in with your user credentials at the command prompt.

Once logged in, run 'amdgpu-pro-uninstall'. This will uninstall all of the AMD Driver and you should be able to boot fine after that (just type 'reboot').

This just happened to me and everything is all fine again, looking to see if theres any updated info for 17.04 yet.

Answer (score 0):

17.04  just came out few days ago. You shouldn't expect good driver support for external Vendors such as AMD.

Linux is especially not "fully compatible" with AMD drivers. My only suggestion is that you purge the drive as **emge** mentioned above and give some time to Ubuntu to fix it, otherwise take a backup and return to 16.10.

That may not to look a solution, but you have **AMD GPU**. Best option is to wait that AMD releases its driver for 17.04(with making it more compatible)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue today with Kubuntu 17.04 and the latest driver for the Radeon R7 240 PCI-E card.  The driver amdgpu-pro-17.10-429170 caused my PC to display a blank screen when booting.  The only solution for me was to un-install the driver using:

amdgpu-pro-uninstall

Then use the onboard (built-in) VGA card used by my motherboard.